# Check alphabets according to a list of numbers

Tags: python

I have a string like

```
p = "asfdasdf"
```

and a list like

```
a = [1,3,6]
```

And I want to check alphabets in the strings, which the numbers in the list indicate. I mean, 's d d' (2rd, 4th, 7th)

I tried this

```
print(p[a])
```

But failed. What should I do?

And for addition, I wonder how I can do things like

print(p[1,3,6])

Is this possible in python? It worked well in R but not in Python.

Comment: you can't access list items quite the way you are asking with `print(p[1,3,6])` but you can get pretty close, and this can be done easily in 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a `list`, and if you want to access any item of a `list`/`string` then you need an index, what are you feeding is a `list` so it won't accept like that.

```
p = "asfdasdf"
a = [1,3,6]
output = []
for i in a:
    output.append(p[i])
print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: There is no need to create a list from p. Strings are already indexable.

Comment: @Z4-tier, Yeah it slipped from my mind, thanks for reminding. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure I understand your question, but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
print([p[x] for x in a])
--> ['s', 'd', 'd']
```

This creates a list comprehension of characters in `p` using the index values in `a` and prints it out in the same line.

if you want it as a string:

```
print(' '.join([p[x] for x in a]))
--> s d d
```

Please also keep in mind one important point: the overall time complexity of your code is not a function of the number of lines. In other words, having fewer lines doesn't mean the code is more efficient (and with Python, it's very easy to make code **less** efficient by trying to make it more compact).

Answer (score 1):

Your `print(p[a])` is not a valid statement in Python. If you are able to do the same in any other language, its because of that language's special feature. In Python, we too something special like that. We call them **list-comprehensions**.

First let's learn, how to get the string character from your string `p`.

```py
>>> p = "asfdasdf"
>>> p
'asfdasdf'
>>> a = [1,3,6]
>>> p[a[1]]
's'
>>> p[a[3]]
'd'
>>> p[a[6]]
'd'
```

Now next step if to construct a string this list of values(`['s', 'd', 'd']`). After that building a string with delimiter as space(). Below is how you do normally

```
my_list = []

for a_i in a:
    my_list.append(p[a_i])
    my_list.append(" ") # adding spaces

# At the end of this above loop, my_list look like ['s', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'd', ' ']


str_out = ""
# now my_list[:-1], look like ['s', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'd'] # exclude last value
for each in my_list[:-1]:
    str_out = str_out + each

print(str_out)
# print `s d d`
```

**List Comprehension**

Now, lets use a list comprehension to generate this list(`[p[each] for each in a]`) and pass this output directly to an inbuilt function. `join` will take care of add space between string variables in that list(`['s', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'd']`) and then combines them to become `s d d`

```py
>>> ' '.join([p[each] for each in a])
's d d'
>>>
```

As one gets used to python, these become quite handy. Also few notable advantageous

- easy to read
- smaller code => less compile-time, less maintenance, fewer chances for errors
- less number of temp variables

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong because if Computer read, it will become

```
p[[1, 3, 6]]
```

Which is illegal and not available in Python, but you can using for statement! You need to use:

Using `for` statement

```
p = "asfdasdf"
a = [1, 3, 6]

for x in a:
 print(p[x], end='')
print('')
```

But this is a dumb way, so instead of using `for` statement, use list comprehension

```
p = "asfdasdf"
a = [1, 3, 6]
print(''.join(p[x] for x in a))
```

Comment: "But this is a dumb way" ... why? Seems perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__getitem__` magic if you want an one-liner, however, using magic directly is discouraged.

```
>>> print(*map(p.__getitem__,a))
s d d
```

Or

```
>>> ''.join(map(p.__getitem__,a))
'sdd'
```

EDIT:

For checking purposes, in order to make sure your code handles indices that are not in string, following code handles missing index by skipping it:

```
>>> p = "asfdasdf"
>>> a = [1,4,7,9]
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(p)}
# d = {0: 'a', 1: 's', 2: 'f', 3: 'd', 4: 'a', 5: 's', 6: 'd', 7: 'f'}
>>> ''.join(d.get(i) for i in a if d.get(i) is not None)
'saf'
```

You can also print custom fillers to indicate index not present:

```
>>> ''.join(d.get(i) if d.get(i) is not None else '_' for i in a)
'saf_'
```